# schedule an event to happen 10 times a second in java

Tags: java

I am making a game that does something 10 times every second in java. I want to make something that schedules this for me What would be a good resource to look at?
EDIT:
Must be original java source.... no external software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a `TimerTask` and scheduling it to run after a particular interval should do the trick..

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //your task
            }
        };
```

schedule it using

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 60*100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at java quartz. it can help you do whatever you want

http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/